# Porque me dice variable duplicada?

Tags: java

eso, les pondre un ejemplo de código de algo que se me hace extraño, ya que en algunas partes me sale duplicada pero en otras, no, exactamente es dentro de un switch. Se que esta el tema de variables locales y globales pero no comprendo que sucede aquí, ejemplo:

```
  switch(op) {

    case 1:     
            registroHab = true;
            int valor; 
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.print("INGRESE el identificador: ");
            int identificador = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("1. Económica");
            System.out.println("2. Delux");
            System.out.println("3. Suit");
            do {
                System.out.print("INGRESE el tipo: (1-3): ");
                valor = sc.nextInt();
            } while(valor < 1 || valor > 3);


            if(valor == 1) {
                tipos[contadorHabitacion] = "Económica";
                } else
                    if(valor == 2) {
                        tipos[contadorHabitacion] = "Delux";
                        } else
                            if(valor == 3) {
                                tipos[contadorHabitacion] = "Suit";
                            }
            System.out.print("INGRESE la cantidad de camas: ");
            int cantCamas = sc.nextInt();

            identificadores[contadorHabitacion] = identificador;
            cantidadCamas[contadorHabitacion] = cantCamas;

            contadorHabitacion++;

            break;
case 2: 
            // Si ya se ha registrado al menos una vez... 
            int indiceModificar;
            if(registroHab == true) {
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("MODIFICAR");
                // Mientras el indice sea mayor que las habitaciones registradas, se va a repetir ya que no existe
                do {
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el indice que desea MODIFICAR (1-"+(contadorHabitacion)+"): ");
                     indiceModificar = sc.nextInt();
                } while(indiceModificar > contadorHabitacion || indiceModificar < 1);

                System.out.println("¿Que desea modificar?");
                System.out.println("1. Identificador");
                System.out.println("2. Tipo (Economica,delux,suit)");
                System.out.println("3. Cantidad de camas");
                System.out.print("Opcion: ");
                int opcion = sc.nextInt();

                if(opcion == 1) {
                System.out.print("Ingrese el nuevo identificador: ");   
                int nuevoIdentificador = sc.nextInt();
                identificadores[indiceModificar-1] = nuevoIdentificador;
                } else
                    if(opcion == 2) {
                        System.out.print("Ingrese el nuevo tipo: (Economico,delux,suit): ");
                        String nuevoTipo = sc.next();
                        tipos[indiceModificar-1] = nuevoTipo;
                    } else 
                        if(opcion == 3) {
                            System.out.print("Ingrese la nueva cantidad de camas: ");
                            int nuevaCantidadCamas = sc.nextInt();
                            cantidadCamas[indiceModificar-1] = nuevaCantidadCamas;
                        }
            } else {
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("NO se han registrado habitaciones");
            }


            break; 
case 3:


            if(registroHab == true) {
                int posicion;
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("ELIMINAR");
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el indice que desea ELIMINAR (1-"+(contadorHabitacion)+")");
                    System.out.print("Posición a eliminar: ");
                    posicion = sc.nextInt();
                }while(posicion < 1 || posicion > contadorHabitacion);

                eliminadoHab[posicion-1] = true;
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("ELIMINACION completa");
            } else {
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("NO se han registrado habitaciones");
            }

            break;
```

Ahi agregue el código, por ejemplo, si quiero duplicar cualquier variable del case 2, en el case 1, no me deja, pero en cambio si lo hago en el case 3 si me deja, eso es a lo que me refiero exactamente,

Ahi agregue el código, por ejemplo, si quiero duplicar cualquier variable del case 2, en el case 1, no me deja, pero en cambio si lo hago en el case 3 si me deja, eso es a lo que me refiero exactamente,

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el bloque `switch` completo, como lo tienes cuando da error? ¿Verificaste que la variable no está declarada en otra parte del código?

Comment: La variable la definí dentro del mismo case, el código completo del switch lo pongo en el post

Comment: El bloque `switch` no está completo en el post, por favor ponlo completo, con su cierre y `default` y todo. En el `case 1` no defines nada, sólo hay un comentario. Se necesita evaluar el problema desde la realidad del código. Y si puedes adjunta también el mensaje de error que da. Gracias.

Comment: Ya agregué el código completo

Comment: cual es la variable que queres agregar.. y donde.. la respuesta que te dieron es tu problema...

Comment: La variable 'int posicion' definida en el case 2, me deja duplicarla en el case 3, pero no me deja duplicarla en el case 1.

Answer (score 1):

Te da error de duplicado porque las variables declaradas pertenecen al mismo scope.

> En programación de computadoras, el **ámbito** o **scope** es el contexto que
>   pertenece a un nombre dentro de un programa. El ámbito determina en
>   qué partes del programa una entidad puede ser usada.

El scope de las variables definidas en cada `case` pertenecen al scope del `switch`. Para evitar esto, puedes crear scopes anidados de la siguiente manera:

```
int op = 2;
switch (op) {
case 1: {
    int x = 1;
    return x;
  }
case 2: {
    int x = 2;
    return x;
  }
}
```